# MongoDB querying for Embeded Document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo document which has structure like

```
{
"_id" : "THIS_IS_A_DHP_USER_ID+2014-11-26",
"_class" : "weight",
"items" : [
    {
        "dateTime" : ISODate("2014-11-26T08:08:38.716Z"),
        "value" : 98.5
    },
    {
        "dateTime" : ISODate("2014-11-26T08:18:38.716Z"),
        "value" : 95.5
    },
    {
        "dateTime" : ISODate("2014-11-26T08:28:38.663Z"),
        "value" : 90.5
    }
],
"source" : "MANUAL",
"to" : ISODate("2014-11-26T08:08:38.716Z"),
"from" : ISODate("2014-11-26T08:08:38.716Z"),
"userId" : "THIS_IS_A_DHP_USER_ID",
"createdDate" : ISODate("2014-11-26T08:38:38.776Z")
}
{
"_id" : "THIS_IS_A_DHP_USER_ID+2014-11-25",
"_class" : "weight",
"items" : [
    {
        "dateTime" : ISODate("2014-11-25T08:08:38.716Z"),
        "value" : 198.5
    },
    {
        "dateTime" : ISODate("2014-11-25T08:18:38.716Z"),
        "value" : 195.5
    },
    {
        "dateTime" : ISODate("2014-11-25T08:28:38.716Z"),
        "value" : 190.5
    }
],
"source" : "MANUAL",
"to" : ISODate("2014-11-25T08:08:38.716Z"),
"from" : ISODate("2014-11-25T08:08:38.716Z"),
"userId" : "THIS_IS_A_DHP_USER_ID",
"createdDate" : ISODate("2014-11-26T08:38:38.893Z")
}
```

The query that want to fire on this document structure, is for finding documents for a particular user id, unwinding the the embedded array and getting the objects that fall between a particular date range.

Can an aggregation be created for such a query or else is this need be solved using map-reduce kind of querying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate it as below:

- `Initialize` the start date and end date variables.
- `Match` the required userId document.
- `Unwind` the items array.
- Use the `$and` operator to `match` the items where the date is in range.
- `Group` together based on `userId`.
- `Project` the required fields.

Code:

```
var startDate = ISODate(); // initialize the correct start date
var endDate = ISODate();  // initialize the correct end date.

db.collection.aggregate([
{$match:{"userId":"THIS_IS_A_DHP_USER_ID"}},
{$unwind:"$items"},
{$match:{$and:[{"items.dateTime":{$gt:startDate}},
               {"items.dateTime":{$lt:endDate}}]}},
{$group:{"_id":"$userId",
         "items":{$push:"$items"},
         "_class":{$first:"$_class"},
         "source":{$first:"$source"},
         "to":{$first:"$to"},
         "from":{$first:"$from"},
         "createdDate":{$first:"$createdDate"}}},
{$project:{"_id":0,
         "items":1,
         "_class":1,
         "source":1,
         "to":1,
         "from":1,
         "createdDate":1,"userId":"$_id"}}
])
```